# Most efficient way to retrieve data from a set of matching id?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, memory

Supose I have a table of different objects with indexed ids which include details about every object and I have another table of choosen objects which each contain the id referencing to the specific object choosen and further details as for example date when object included as choosen. So it can be seen as something like this:

```
              objects                    choosen objects
    +-------------------------+    +-------------------------+
    | objID   | image| ...    |    | objID   | date | ...    |
    +-------------------------+    +-------------------------+
    | 1       | ...  | ...    |    | 2       | ...  | ...    |
    | 2       | ...  | ...    |    | 3       | ...  | ...    |
    | 3       | ...  | ...    |    | 5       | ...  | ...    |
    +-------------------------+    +-------------------------+
```

Now in my php file I access all the choosen objects with following query:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root', 'objects')or die('not connecting');
$sql="SELECT * FROM choosen;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$id=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($id,$row["objID"]);
}
```

This way I want to use the objects ids from choosen objects table to reference those objects with same id in order to show on screen the object´s image as other details contained in the objects table. So for that I get the following code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root', 'objects')or die('not connecting');
foreach($array_id as $i){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM objects WHERE objID=".$id.";";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    display($row);
}
```

Nevertheless  I´m afraid that the fact of having to call multiple query requests for looping the choosen objects and retrieving their details as their images would cause an uneffective and slow data retrieving. I wonder if there is a most effective way to retrieve data from objects table which would be more time and query cost saving, or if on the other hand it would be preferable to duplicate and spread the image and further objects data to the choosen objects table when created, sacrificing memory cost in exchange for time and query saving. I would like to hear your advantages of any decision and recommendations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be joining the two tables with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM objects o
INNER JOIN choosen c
    ON o.objID = c.objID
```

This avoids so many unnecessary roundtrips to and from your MySQL database.  Sample code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root', 'objects')or die('not connecting');

$sql = "SELECT o.* FROM objects o INNER JOIN choosen c ON o.objID = c.objID";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
// iterate and display result set here
```

Note that if you wanted to initially restrict the query on the `choosen` table to particular `ID`, you could use a prepared statement with your `mysqli` code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Biegeleisen mentioned you can join table. To make it easier, create a view as bellow

```
CREATE VIEW v_objects AS
   SELECT o.* FROM objects o
   INNER JOIN choosen c ON o.objID = c.objID
```

Inside PHP

```
...
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM v_objects");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
...
```

Comment: There's nothing 'easier' about a view